# Change NvaigationView SubHeader color

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-support-library

I have a navigationview that has a subheader and I want to change the text color, I tried everything I know and nothing works.

That is my menu:
[image]

I want to change the "sub" text color and the list divider color.

Any idea?

My Code:

`menu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:checked="true"
        android:title="teste"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_2"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="teste"/>
</group>

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_subheader"
    android:title="sub">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_sub_item_1"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:title="teste"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_sub_item_2"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:title="teste"/>
    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
[...]
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/menu_item"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/headerMenuTextDisabled"
    android:layout_above="@+id/version"
    />
[...]
```

`menu_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/headerMenuText" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/headerMenuTextDisabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:color="@color/headerMenuText"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FF0000</item> would change the sub header title color of navigation view.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom theme for your navigation drawer and set **textColorSecondary** to the color you want.

In themes.xml

```
<resources>
   <style name="NavigationDrawerTheme" parent="YourOwnBaseTheme">
   <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FFF000</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
   android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
   android:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerTheme" />
```

Alternatively you can benefit from 3rd party implementations of navigation drawer which has already solved this and many other problems (such as divider color):

https://github.com/oprisnik/navdrawer

https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer